# How to substitute a block of lines inside a file?

Tags: awk, sed, perl

I want to change the multi-line contain `foo2` to be like desired output
`foo2` is like an array in multiline, how to change it to be in one line

- **FROM:**

```bsh
$ cat file.txt
foo1=bar1
foo2=('bar10: some text here'
      'bar11: anther text here'
       ...
      'bar: final text here')
foo3=('bar3')
foo=1.2.33
```

- **TO:**

```bsh
foo1=bar1
foo2="bar10 bar11 .. bar"
foo3=('bar3')
foo=1.2.33
```

Comment: oki i will remove

Comment: why would you want to do that?   `foo2` looks like a good candidate for converting to an associative array (with keys like bar, bar10, bar11, etc and values like "some text here" etc).  A space separated string is a poor substitute for an array (and will cause you all sorts of problems and annoyances). It's easy - even in a language like bash - to get a list of all the keys of the array, if that's what you need.

Comment: - to install an app that doesn't in Archlinux by Pacman, you must create a file PKGBUILD, this file tells to Pacman how to download, extract, compiled, and install from GitHub or any other site...  
- void Linux use file called template is similar to `PKGBUILD`, but with different syntax  
- I'm trying to convert `PKGBUILD` to `template`.

Comment: If you don't literally have a string that's `...` in your real input and `..` in your expected output then please [edit] your question to remove them from your example so we have something we can copy/paste to test with.

Comment: it's doing a good job for me and anyone wants to use awk to substitute multi-line, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box and assuming that `...` line in your input and `..` string in your output don't literally exist in your real data and are intended to represent text similar to the text around them:

```
$ cat tst.awk
(val=="") && /.*\047$/ {
    tag = $0
    sub(/=.*/,"",tag)
    val = ""
}
tag != "" {
    split($0,f,/[\047:]/)
    val = (val == "" ? "" : val " ") f[2]
    if ( /\)$/ ) {
        print tag "=\"" val "\""
        tag = ""
    }
    next
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file.txt
foo1=bar1
foo2="bar10 bar11 bar"
foo3=('bar3')
foo=1.2.33
```

Comment: It works, thank you, did you give me a name of a good book for advanced awk learning?

Comment: You're welcome. Beginner, advanced and everything in between - Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 1):

with `sed` :

```
sed -n '/^foo2=(/ba;p;d;:a N;/)$/!ba;s/\n//g;s/  */ /gp' file1
```

---

with `perl`

```perl
perl -pe '
    $_ = /[)]$/ ? s/  */ /gr : 
    (substr $_, 0, -1) =~ s/  */ /gr
        if /^foo2=[(]/ .. /[)]$/
' test
```

or if your `perl` version doesn't have the `r` modifier for the `s`ubstitution:

```perl
perl -pe '
    $_ = /[)]$/ ? $_ : substr $_, 0, -1 and s/  */ /g 
        if /^foo2=[(]/ .. /[)]$/
' test
```